# Is there a way to make Simple Injector only call a delegate once for a Transient registration?

Tags: simple-injector

I have some conditional registration dependent on a configuration setting. The code works fine but while debugging I noticed that the delegate is getting called every time the IDocumentService is requested.

```
container.Register<IDocumentService>(() =>
{
    switch (Environment.UserConfiguration.RealDocumentPersistenceType)
    {
        case DocumentPersistenceType.Sql:
        case DocumentPersistenceType.Disk:
            return container.GetInstance<DocumentService>();
        case DocumentPersistenceType.IManage:
            return container.GetInstance<IManageDocumentService>();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Environment.UserConfiguration.RealDocumentPersistenceType),
                Environment.UserConfiguration.RealDocumentPersistenceType.ToString());
    }
}, Lifestyle.Transient);
```

The documentation states that the delegate is only called once for a "**single instance**", which makes sense, but is there a way to tell SI that although this registration is Transient, every time it is requested, return the type used on the first call?

[image: Simple Injector Delegate documentation]

Answer (score 0):

Just move the switch out of the registration:

```cs
switch (Environment.UserConfiguration.RealDocumentPersistenceType)
{
   case DocumentPersistenceType.Sql:
   case DocumentPersistenceType.Disk:
       container.Register<IDocumentService, DocumentService>();
       break;

    case DocumentPersistenceType.IManage:
       container.Register<IDocumentService, ManageDocumentService>();
       break;

    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); } }, Lifestyle.Transient);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Steven, I checked this and we are using the delegate because the service registration happens before the other information is available. The switch can only be done once the Environment.UserConfiguration has been loaded from the DB and we need the other services first in order to do that. Would like a way for SI to use a delegate AND a single call as it does with Singleton.

Comment: Just had one of my posts deleted by a Moderator because I said "Thanks" so I am editing my comment to remove the word "Thanks" but rest assured I am still appreciative of what you offered. This comment will also be deleted so enjoy it while you can :)